# Lottie File not working in the browser but showing in the bootstrap studio interface

Tags: bootstrap-5, lottie, bootstrap-studio

Lottie File showing as component in the bootstrap studio interface and shpoing previe but not showing in the browser and it is disapearing.

Does anyone faced the same problem and solved?

Answer (score 0):

After Long time spending I tried using dotlottie player and linked dot lottie player as scripted. Then after several hard refresh I found it works.

To do that I convert lottie component to `HTML` Then took designed code snippet as below:

```
<dotlottie-player src="https://lottie.host/a480f2a2-114e-40be-a79e-152f88ff658f/NdXyD3wHrM.json" background="transparent" speed="1" style="width: 100%; height: auto;mix-blend-mode:multiply;" class="d-block m-auto" loop autoplay></dotlottie-player>
```

before that below script added to the bootstrap studio script panel:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@dotlottie/player-component@latest/dist/dotlottie-player.mjs" type="module"></script>
```